# Dropdown container plugin

Tags: html, css, jquery

There are times when I want to put a button on a HTML page and dropdown a div (like a mega menu) when the button is clicked. All the plugins I've found so far either require data in unordered lists or in a nav element. Are there any mega dropdown plugins that work on single button elements and allow custom html to be dropped down?

Answer (score 1):

After some fiddling, turns out bootstrap can do this out of the box:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Example <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 10px;">
        HTML code here
    </div>
</div>
```

However, for those not using bootstrap, I also found [this](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/), which supports dropdown panels.